# Get Wpf DataGrid data in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

i have a `datagrid` and i am populating it with data from a list. now i want to get back all the data in my `datagrid` to a list. how can i ?

```
<DataGrid Name="InstrumentGrid"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                      Margin="0,16,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="19" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Width="422" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="NCS Date" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker BorderThickness="0" Height="20" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instrument No" Binding="{Binding NcsNo}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bank Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding BankName}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Width="10" Margin="5 0 0 0" Height="10" Stretch="Fill" Source="/InstrumentManagement;component/wrongSign.png"></Image>
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Loading data into DataGrid**

```
private List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
public VehicleInOutWnd()
{
    InitializeComponent();



    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Data()
        {
            Id = i.ToString(),
            BankName = "Bank al habib"+i,
            NcsDate = "23/12/2018",
            InstrumentNo = "234"+i,
            Type = "Type abc"+i
        });
    }

    InstrumentGrid.ItemsSource = list;

}
```

Now i just want to get all this data in `DataGrid`, as it was in `list<Data>` in some other list. on a `button` click function.

Comment: The modified data is still in `list`. Can't you get it from there?

Comment: data gets modified in original list if don't get two way binding ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit a cell in the `DataGrid`, you are setting the corresponding property of the `Data` class in `list`. So all edited data is already in `list`. Just get it from there before you clear the original list:

```
var modifiedData = list.ToList(); //creates a copy of the list that contains the modified data
list.Clear(); //clears the original list.
```

Comment: original list changes if only i use two way binding. only then the original list updates the changes made in DataGrid. i resolved this using two way binding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the data from the datagrid after changing it. If you bind your initial List list (confusing naming here) to the datagrid, it would always be updated without manual interference.

The cleanest solution would be to use a viewmodel.

```
public class MyViewModel {
    : INotifyPropertyChanged

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _myDataList = new List<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            _myDataList.Add(new Data()
            {
                Id = i.ToString(),
                BankName = "Bank al habib"+i,
                NcsDate = "23/12/2018",
                InstrumentNo = "234"+i,
                Type = "Type abc"+i
            });
        }
    }

    private List<Data> _myDataList;
    public List<Data> MyDataList { 
        get { return _myDataList; }
        set
            {
                _myDataList = value;
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyDataList"));
            }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This class contains the logic to create your datalist, further additions to your view can also be added onto this. The INotifyPropertyChanged ensures that the screen is in sync with the data you're putting in the code.

This allows you to just create a viewmodel and put it as the datacontext of your view.

```
private MyViewModel _viewModel;
public VehicleInOutWnd()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;

    public void ClickButton() 
    {
        // You could just access _viewModel.MyDataList for an up-to-date list.
    }
}
```

The XAML would change to the following to accomodate the new datacontext.

```
<DataGrid Name="InstrumentGrid"
                      ItemsSource={Binding MyDataList}
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                      Margin="0,16,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="19" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Width="422" Grid.Column="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

If all properties of your Data class are value type create new List

```
var originalList = InstrumentGrid.ItemsSource as List<Data>;
var anotherList= new List<Data>(originalList);
```

But if your Data class has refrence type members, you should 
add a copy-constructor method in your class which will initialize Data and
then you can clone your list like this

```
originalList.ForEach((item)=>
    {
        anotherList.Add(new Data(item));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting DataContext of the grid.

Let's say you want that list on button click, you can write button click handler in the xaml.cs, then code would be something similar to:

```
var list = (List<Data>)InstrumentGrid.DataSource;
viewModel.ProcessListofData(list);
```

Comment: no 1 i am not using any model ! no 2 the data in datagrid is modified. and the previous list<Data> that was assigned to dataGrid is cleared . no i want to iterate through datagrid and get all the modified data in a list

Comment: I am not sure how the grid data is getting bound.  You can setup two way binding and that way you would still be able to use the above code to get the data source.